# Create a string from inserted.id via trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm creating a trigger on insert that will create a new record in another table using the id from the newly inserted row.

I need to format the id before I insert it into the other table. This is my code so far.... having problems creating the formated @PseudoID.

```
CREATE TRIGGER OnInsertCreateUnallocatedPseudo 
   ON  tblTeams 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    DECLARE @PseudoID NVARCHAR(50), @tmID NVARCHAR(10)

    SELECT @tmID = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),inserted.tmID) FROM inserted

    --NEED SOME CODE TO CREATE A PADDED OUT PseudoID e.g.
    -- if @tmID =  '7' then @PseudoID = 'PSU0007'
    -- if @tnID = '25' then @PseudoID = 'PSU0025'


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblUsersPseudo].....
END
```

Comment: @DaleK Not quite following you... but if there were more than one record in inserted then I'd be hoping that the trigger would create a record in tblUserPseudo for each one in inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign it to a variable within the trigger since there could be multiple rows, but you could do something like this to insert into the other table.

```
LEFT('PSU0000',LEN('PSU0000')-LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),inserted.tmID))) + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),inserted.tmID)
```

Comment: Ah... now I understand what Dale was trying to explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't assume that `Inserted` has only a single row, you have to treat it as a table with 0-N rows and carry out set-based operations on it (rather than procedural).
2. `FORMAT` will format your existing id into the new format you require.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblUsersPseudo] (id, col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT FORMAT(id,'PSU0000')
      , col1, col2
    FROM Inserted;
```

Comment: I went with WAMLeslie's solution as it came in before yours... but like the simplicity of your FORMAT suggestion so may try that.

Comment: Thats fine you are free to select any answer, doesn't need to be the first though - should be whichever one you felt is most useful.